# Kunneth Formula for $H_\ast(S^1\times(S^1 \vee S^1))$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, path-connected

I'm trying to compute the homology groups of $A=S^1\times(S^1 \vee S^1)$ with integer coefficients using Kunneth Formula. I have a few questions

Here's the formula (omitting coefficients): $H_k(X \times Y)\cong \oplus_{i+j=k} H_i(X) \otimes H_j(Y) \oplus_{i+j=k-1} \mbox{Tor}(H_i(X),H_j(Y))$.

Should I always include the case when $i=j=0$? How would the Tor part of the formula work for $k=0$?

I know $H_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \cong H_0(S^1) \cong H_0(S^1 \vee S^1)$ and $H_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

By the formula, $H_1(A) \cong H_0(S^1) \otimes H_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \oplus H_1(S^1) \otimes H_0(S^1 \vee S^1) \oplus \mbox{Tor}(H_0(S^1),H_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \oplus \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$

Have I made any mistake in my calculation? Can it be simplified further?

I saw online that $\mbox{Tor}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=0$, but why is this true? How exactly do I calculate $\mbox{Tor}(G,H)$ for any two groups $G$ and $H$.

Also, how do I know if the space $A$ is path connected, i.e. $H_0(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For $k> 0$ we always understand $H_{-k}X=0$ when $H$ is ordinary homology. You should always include the case $i,j=0$, otherwise the formula does not return the correct answer (consider $H_1(S^1\times S^1)$). Note that $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong H_1S^1\oplus H_1S^1\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. Homology is always abelian. Note also that $H_2(S^1(S^1\vee S^1))$ is nonzero.

Comment: I would suggest that if you do not understand the terms in the formula, then you should be trying to understand what they are before asking how to blindly apply the formula. If you do not have a basic understanding of homological algebra, then you will get little from homology.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks. I accidentally put in $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ for $H_1$ which should have been a red flag because as you mentioned, homology must be abelian. Why would $H_2(A)$ be nonzero? $A$ doesn't have any cells of dimension larger than 1. Also, yes I've been trying to dig into calculating Tor of two groups. Do you have any suggestion for resources? I'm struggling to find something that explain how to calculate Tor.

Comment: The torus $S^1\times S^1$ retracts off $A=S^1\times (S^1\vee S^1)$ in at least two obvious ways, so $A$ cannot have nonzero $H_2$. In particular $A$ must have 2-cells. Which text are you learning homology from?

Comment: Including 0 homology information in the Kunneth formula is analogous to including 0-cell information in the CW structure on the product of two complexes. It counts homology coming from the copy of $X$ in $X \times Y$ coming from $X \times \{y_i\} $ where $y_i$ are the 0-cells.

Comment: @Tyrone I see. Now I see that also since this is a direct product, certainly it has a two cell which is the product of two one cells. I'm using Algebraic Topology by Hatcher. It mentions the Tor functor a few times, but I'm not seeing how to calculate it.

Comment: See $\S3.A$ pg. 263 (lastest online copy). The table of contents is your friend.